# Unable to display image from database - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a relationship with product and images. The user can upload many images for a product so I have a product table and product_images table.

When I try to get to fetch the image from the database, I get No image available in my view. But I am able to save to the path attribute in my database.

Why could this be happening?

**product_images**

```
id

product_id

path
```

**Product**

```
public function images()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
}
```

**Image**

```
 public function products()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
 }
```

**Controller**

```
     public function index()
     {   
         $products = Product::where('type', 'BASIC')->inRandomOrder()->take(6)->get();
         return view('home.index',compact('products');   
     }

 $product_image = Product::create($request->all());

        if ($request->hasFile('image'))
         {
            $request->file('image')->store('uploads/catalog/images');

            // ensure every image has a different name
            $file_name = $request->file('image')->hashName();

            // save new image $file_name to database
            $product_image->images()->update(['image' => $file_name]);
        }
```

**View**

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    @foreach($product->image as $img)
      <div class="product-item men">
          <div class="product discount product_filter">
              <div class="product_image">
                <a  href="{{ route('product.view', $product->slug)}}"><img src="{{$img}}" alt=""></a>
              </div>
              <!-- <div class="favorite favorite_left"></div> -->
              <!-- <div class="product_bubble product_bubble_right product_bubble_red d-flex flex-column align-items-center"><span>offer</span></div> -->
              <div class="product_info">
                <h6 class="product_name"><a href="{{ route('product.view', $product->slug)}}">{{$product->name}}</a></h6>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**dd($img)**

```
ProductImage {#523 ▼
  #fillable: array:3 [▼
    0 => "product_id"
    1 => "path"
    2 => "is_main_image"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:6 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "product_id" => 1
    "path" => "/Users/emmnock/laravel-ecommerce/public/uploads/catalog/ZsT4VwjWS5tLvIl0AKV6sAOxHFrwzwII5FMVUVkP.png"
    "is_main_image" => null
    "created_at" => "2018-03-07 10:04:34"
    "updated_at" => "2018-03-07 10:04:34"
  ]
  #original: array:6 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Comment: `$product->image` should probably be `$product->images` in your `@foreach`

Comment: in your relation you have $product->images and in your foreach you are doing $product->image it should be $product->images and {{$img->path}}

Comment: @rchatburn, i get this error  `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: @kerbholz, i am getting the error as shown in the coment

Comment: dd($img) and post the results

Comment: @rchatburn please check the update when i dd($img)

Answer (score 0):

if your image is in `public` folder then use `asset()`

Here is an example

```
<img src="{{ asset(str_replace(app_path(),'',$img->path))}}" alt="">
```

also in your `foreach`
use below given code

```
 @foreach($product->images as $img)
```

If it is storage folder then move the image to storage then use asset() or create a symlink

use `asset(str_replace(app_path(),'',$img->path))`

Hope this helps

Comment: `src="{{ asset($img)}}"` still gives image not available but hen i do src="{{ asset($img->path)}}", i get this error  `preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given `

Comment: @foreach($product->images as $img)

Comment: @XamarinDevil you are missing  @foreach($product->images as $img)

Comment: @XamarinDevil use $product->images

Comment: Yes.. i have used that and still getting the same error

Comment: lol. sorry check my update. thought pictures were not allowed

Comment: @XamarinDevil Sorry my advise, but you'd better learn html first.

Comment: dd() outside the img tag

Comment: @shukshin.ivan check my update and thanks for your advise

Comment: @laravellevaral how is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `img` object to echo it. `Image` must have some properties like `url` or `path`, so you can output them only. Looks like you store full path (why?) inside `path` property.

```
$url = str_replace(public_path(), "", $img->path);
<img src="{{ $url }}" alt="">
```

If you store filename as an image property, so get url to it.

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url($img->path_to_file) }}" alt="">
```

Comment: Your `dd` is not a `dd` at all :) How do you store image file contents? Why do you need to echo it?

Comment: Looks like you call `dd()` inside the img tag :) Why?!)

Comment: I have updated my dd() results and check my controller how i store my file content

Comment: @XamarinDevil check the updated answer (first part of it)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with how you store the image in the database.

```
$request->file('image')->store('uploads/catalog/images');
// ensure every image has a different name
$file_name = $request->file('image')->hashName();
// save new image $file_name to database
$product_image->images()->update(['image' => $file_name]);
```

You are using `store()` to save the file, then you are generating a new file name using `hashName()` and that is no way related to the image file that has been stored in `'uploads/catalog/images'`.

The proper way would be to get the full path of the image stored returned by the `store()` method, and save that in the database.

```
$image_path = $request->file('image')->store('uploads/catalog/images');
$product_image->images()->update(['image' => $image_path]);
```